# How do I Setup WiFi in Parrot Security OS Virtual Box?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I have recently installed PSOS (Parrot Security OS) on Virtual Box but now I can't get WiFi on the VB. I'm using Ubuntu as my Main OS and Parrot as my VB.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to expand upon what you have tried and the make and model of your wifi adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox have created a virtual computer inside your ubuntu host, and as a virtual computer, it has virtualized all its hardware too, including the network card

virtualbox creates a virtual network card (like a virtual ethernet cable) attached to the VM and NATted behind the connection that your ubuntu host has already established

you can't use your wifi card directly in your VM as it is impossible to make 2 operating systems use the same hardware device at the same time

the only solution is to do a pci/usb passthrough, that means that the wifi chipset will be detached from ubuntu and atached to the virtual machine (keeping your ubuntu host offline and giving to parrot the ability to scan wifi networks, intercept traffic and to wireless testing)

another solution is to buy an external wifi dongle and attach it to the virtual machine with usb passthrough, if you don't have one already and you need to buy one (and if your intentions are to do wireless security tests), then the official parrot documentation portal offers a list of devices featuring some chipsets with full sniffing/injection support (https://docs.parrotsec.org/doku.php/supported-wifi-devices)

the best one should be the TP-LINK TL-WN722N

there is another solution that you can try

virtualbox creates a NATted virtual network for your virtual machine, that means that the virtual machine can access the internet but not your local network (LAN)

if you change the setup of your VM from 'NAT' to 'bridge' then your virtual machine will be able to see all the other machines in your LAN (but of course no wireless testing here)